# Android Studio and Android SDK 25 glob()

Tags: android, android-ndk

In my Android project I use the glob.h functions for path handling. I currently use Android Version 29 as minimum. Now for ChromeOS I use the Android Version 25 and I get compile errors in with NDK and my external lib.

"use of undeclared identifier 'glob'"

After research this issue I found out that this is first supported in Android Version 28. 
Anybody has an idea how to solve this in Android Version 25? Is it possible to add the own glob classes to the code?

Answer (score 0):

The source is here: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:bionic/libc/upstream-freebsd/lib/libc/gen/glob.c

I don't know how self-contained it is (the upstream BSD code rarely is), so it might be a bit of a pain to actually copy into your project. You may need to copy a few other headers (or at least the relevant pieces) to make it work. Your other options would be finding an alternative implementation that you can depend on or re-implementing it yourself though, so it may be your best bet.